# How can I receive a set of data from a query while sending a parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, winforms

I get an exception I don't understand:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'Clienti'.'

This is my code leading up to the error:

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=VONWOLFENSPC\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=Gestionare_excursii_agentie_turism;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString: connectionString);

string selectsql = "Select G.Nume, G.Prenume, G.Telefon, G.NumarInsotitori, " +
                    "G.ClientID, G.Sex, " +
                    "(Select E.Nume From Excursii E where E.ExcursieID LIKE G.ExcursieID) AS Excursie" +
                    "From Clienti G Where G.CNP Like @cnp";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectsql, sqlCon);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", comboBox2.Text);

try
{
    sqlCon.Open();

    // error happens on the next line
    using (SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(read.Read())
        {
             //...

        }
    }
}
finally
{
    sqlCon.Close();
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: At first glance, you are missing a space ` ` character between the `FROM` clause and the alias `Excursie`. Add the space and then report back

Comment: That was it and I tried for 1 hour to solve it and nothing =)). Thanks, you're awesome.

Comment: @VonWolfen I am somewhat uncertain, but you might be trying to reinvent the join with that 2nd Select.

Comment: Unrelated tips: SqlConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable so each should be in a `using` block. Once you've done that, you don't need to Close the connection because it will be closed by the implicit Dispose as it exits the block. Also, you may want to read [can we stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you have is just spaces, if you tried to recheck the string you'll notice a missing space before FROM.

Also, you need to use `using`

```
    string selectsql =  @"SELECT  
                            G.Nume
                        ,   G.Prenume
                        ,   G.Telefon
                        ,   G.NumarInsotitori
                        ,   G.ClientID
                        ,   G.Sex
                        ,   (SELECT E.Nume FROM Excursii E WHERE E.ExcursieID LIKE G.ExcursieID) AS Excursie
                        FROM 
                            Clienti G 
                        WHERE 
                            G.CNP LIKE @cnp";

    using(SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectsql, sqlCon) )
    using(SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", comboBox2.Text);        

        sqlCon.Open();

        while(read.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = (read["Nume"].ToString());
            textBox2.Text = (read["Prenume"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (read["Telefon"].ToString());
            textBox4.Text = (read["NumarInsotitori"].ToString());
            textBox5.Text = (read["ClientID"].ToString());
            comboBox1.Text = (read["Excursie"].ToString());
            string sex = (read["Sex"].ToString());
            if (sex == "M")
            {
                checkBox1.Checked = true;
                checkBox2.Checked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                checkBox2.Checked = true;
                checkBox1.Checked = false;
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of concatenating the query, use a multi-line string literal:

```
    string selectsql = @"
Select  G.Nume, G.Prenume, G.Telefon, G.NumarInsotitori, G.ClientID, G.Sex, 
       (
         Select E.Nume 
         From Excursii E 
         where E.ExcursieID LIKE G.ExcursieID
        ) AS Excursie
From Clienti G 
Where G.CNP Like @cnp
";
```

Which you can paste directly to/from a SSMS query window for testing.